# jquery - How to interact with a class element within an id of an element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Can somebody show me how to find a class element within an element id?

1: I want to find the class name `close` within the id `'message_sent'` so that it closes that id element block if i click on that specific close icon.

2: I want to find the class name `close` within the id `'mailing_list_email_sent'` so that it closes that id element block if i click on that specific close icon.

Below is the html and js code:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("message_sent");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Get the modal
var modalMailingMsg = document.getElementById("mailing_list_email_sent");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spanCloseMailingMsg = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
spanCloseMailingMsg.onclick = function() {
  modalMailingMsg.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="message_sent">
  <p>
    Message successfully sent!
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  </p>
</section>';

<section id="mailing_list_email_sent">
  <p>
    Message successfully sent!
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  </p>
</section>';
```

Comment: `$('#parentid .child-class')`  Fairly straight forward.  Same way as you would make a css rule.

Comment: You've tagged this [jquery] but are conspicuously not using jQuery in your code. If you want to continue not using jQuery, just use the element with the id as the scope of the search, not `document`, so `modal.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]`, or more succinctly, `modal.querySelector(".close")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the *id* you can probably use the *tag* name:

**Demo:**

```js
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spanList = document.querySelectorAll(".close");
spanList.forEach(function(span){
  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.addEventListener('click',function() {
    this.closest("section").style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```html
<section id="message_sent">
  <p>
    Message 1 successfully sent!
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  </p>
</section>

<section id="mailing_list_email_sent">
  <p>
    Message 2 successfully sent!
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: This code makes some assumptions about the order of the elements with the class "close" in the document order. If the user cut and pasted the element with an id of "message_sent" after that with "mailing_list_email_sent", this code would break. Or if there was another element with that class interposed between those two elements which had nothing to do with this behavior...

Comment: There's a small issue with this. So in the example provided it's fine because we have two class elements, so there's a 0 and 1. But in other pages, there is only mailing_list_email_sent and no message_sent, that's why I want to look for a specific element first and then the close element within

Comment: PErfect :) Thanks Mamun

Answer (score 0):

message_sent > close

```
$('#message_sent .close')
```

mailing_list_email_sent > close

```
$('#mailing_list_email_sent .close')
```

You can also use vanilla js:

```
document.querySelector('#message_sent .close');
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but when I click on the close icons, they do not close down the relevant message blocks

Answer (score 0):

To do with with the least amount of code would be to use jQuery (and a little ES2015 sytax sugar):

Note I'm using event delegation here so that you can add more of these notifications after this code has been parsed, and you won't have to add more code.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.close', (e) => $(e.target).closest('section').hide());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="message_sent">
  <p>
    Message successfully sent!
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  </p>
</section>';

<section id="mailing_list_email_sent">
  <p>
    Message successfully sent!
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  </p>
</section>';
```

Without jQuery, it's pretty much the same, just a little more verbose. Same deal with event delegation; just here I need to check if the current target has the "close" class, then I added a CSS class that will hide it. I used CSS classes like this in case I want to add CSS transitions later on.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => 
  e.target.classList.contains('close') && 
  e.target.closest('section').classList.add('hide'));
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="message_sent">
  <p>
    Message successfully sent!
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  </p>
</section>';

<section id="mailing_list_email_sent">
  <p>
    Message successfully sent!
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
  </p>
</section>';
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution with pure js:

```
document.querySelector('section#message_sent span.close').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let closeBtn = e.target;
    let messageSentSection = closeBtn.closest('section');

    messageSentSection.style.display = 'none';
});

document.querySelector('section#mailing_list_email_sent span.close').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let closeBtn = e.target;
    let mailingListEmailSentSection = closeBtn.closest('section');

    mailingListEmailSentSection.style.display = 'none';
});
```